# pandas fill only group meeting criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-cleaning

How do you fill only groups inside a dataframe which are not fully nulls?

In the dataframe below, only groups with `df.A=b` and `df.A=c` should get filled.

```
df
     A    B
0    a    NaN
1    a    NaN
2    a    NaN
3    a    NaN
4    b    4.0
5    b    NaN
6    b    6.0
7    b    6.0
8    c    7.0
9    c    NaN
10   c    NaN
```

Was thinking something like:
`if set(df[df.A==(need help here)].B.values) == {np.nan}:`.

Answer (score 1):

We can do `groupby`

```
df.B=df.groupby('A').B.apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())
```

Comment: That'd be for normal filling, but how do you check if the group is not nan-only in that column?

Comment: @DanielB it will check , if all NaN , there is nothing to fill

Answer (score 0):

Get the indices that are not completely null, and then `forwardfill`/`backwardfill` on these indices

```
df = df.set_index("A")

#get index where entries in B are not completely full
ind = df.loc[df.groupby("A").B.transform(lambda x: x.eq(x))].index.unique()

df.loc[ind] = df.loc[ind].ffill().bfill()


print(df)

     B
A   
a   NaN
a   NaN
a   NaN
a   NaN
b   4.0
b   4.0
b   6.0
b   6.0
c   7.0
c   7.0
c   7.0
```